# Как правильно делать выборку из базы данных?

Tags: база-данных, php, sql

Всем добрый день! Есть база данных на sql. Допустим такой пример, человек авторизуется на сайте, берем обычный SELECT FROM WHERE и перебираем всю таблицу и ищем указанный email. А если таких записей 10 000 или 100 000? Как в этом случае извлекать нужные данные? Не хочется что бы при каждом запросе ворошила бы всю таблицу. 
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Сделать индекс по полю email и будет счастье. Ничего страшного в таком поиске нет. Какая СУБД?

Comment: MySQl база данных. Как можно сделать index по полю email? И как эта штука будет потом работать,! всегда хотел это понять!

Comment: для десяти, ста тысяч или даже нескольких миллионов любая нормальная СУБД способна выбрать одну запись по индексированному полю в течение очень маленького промежутка времени. Как говорится, глазом не успеете моргнуть. 10 тысяч - это вообще не размер для таких задач.

Comment: А как работает выборка по индексированному полю?

Comment: Почитай что такое индекс в mysql и как он работает. В любом мануале есть.грубо говоря он не будет икать в самой таблице, а будет искать по индексу. Так же как и ты ищешь номер в справочнике. Ты же не читаешь всю книгу.

Comment: >А как работает выборка по индексированному полю?

быстро) Если вас интересует синтаксис, то точно такжэе, как и по неиндексированному. Вы же наверняка делали выборку по первичному ключу? Многие СУБД автоматически создают индексы по первичным ключам. Следовательно, вы могли делать подобные выборки, сами того не подозревая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй индекс и limit 1 и оно не будет ворошить всю таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать индексы. А вот здесь автор очень подробно описывает про индексы: [Индексы MySQL](http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%B2+MySQL)